# jQuery DataTables - fnFilter doesn't work with regex

Tags: jquery, regex, datatables, filtering

I'm working with DataTables 1.10.11 and filtering the data by columns using the built-in fnFilter function.

In general, it's working fine, but when I try to filter a column using the regex option, it doesn't work.

For example:

```
var table = jQuery("#mytable").dataTable();
```

While this works just fine:

```
table.fnFilter("aaa", 0);
```

This doesn't work:

```
table.fnFilter("aaa|bbb", 0, true);
```

Am I missing something here? Do I have to set anything more than just the "true" option when setting the filter to work as regex?

This is the initial setup of the related code:

```
jQuery("#mytable").dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            responsive: true,
            ordering: true,
            order: [1, 'desc'],
            bPaginate: false,
            fnInitComplete: function ()
            {
                // something happens here...
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the fourth parameter as false.

```
table.fnFilter("aaa|bbb", 0, true, false);
```

Comment: As simple as that...  :)  I was aware of the boolean option for the regex thing, but wasn't aware of the additional boolean option... Thanks!!